# Is it better to duplicate an object to store old values?

Tags: java

I have a page where I can edit an object's values in Java. However, I would need to store and pass the object's old values as well for the Stored Procedure.

For this, I duplicated the object like so:

```
public void onClickEdit(Education e) {
    Education edOld = new Education(e);
    Education edNew = new Education(e);
    goToPage(a);
}
```

I also made it so that the user will only edit `edNew` in the edit page.

The Education class has a constructor that sets another Education class' attributes as its own, like so:

```
public class Education {

    private int educationID;
    private String educationName;
    private String educationStatus;

    public Education() { }

    public Education(Education e) {
        educationID = e.getEducationID();
        educationName = e.getEducationName();
        educationStatus = e.getEducationStatus();
    }

    // setter-getters ...

}
```

My question is, would it be better on the memory to have a single class that has attributes for new and old attributes - like this:

```
    private int educationID;
    private String educationName;
    private String educationStatus;

    private int old_educationID;
    private String old_educationName;
    private String old_educationStatus;
```

or is the way that I am doing it fine as well?

Comment: I vote for your current approach, l which uses a copy constructor.  It seems like possibly bad design for one object to keep track of the state of two objects.

Comment: What you're referring to is called a 'copy constructor' and is perfectly fine practice. You should not be concerned about what will be "better on the memory" at such a fine-grained level. The difference will be so insignificant as to not be worth considering. You should do whatever makes the most sense conceptually, which is the former example using the copy constructor.